# how to transfer file from OPC UA client to OPC UA Server

Tags: file-transfer, file-type, opc-ua, open62541

I'm using open62541 to run a server on my embedded device(stm32f429), as a client I use UAExpert to connect to the server and borowse the nodes.

My problem is that I want to upload a file from Client "UAExpert" to my Server. I found a similiar question [here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57685714/how-to-transfer-files-from-opc-ua-client-to-server/58832497#58832497) but the answer didn't help me a lot.

I read the Annex C in part 5 but I couldn't understand how to implement the methods on the server side.

Can any one help me?

thnx in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transfer Files from OPC UA Client to Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57685714/how-to-transfer-files-from-opc-ua-client-to-server)

Comment: i worte that i found it, but it is not so clear how to write those method like open, read, close ... i can understand it if i write application for windwos/linux but how should i do open a file usind uC?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that UAExpert supports this feature.

UAExpert can display Image from OPC UA Variable values from the Server (So actually if the Variable is writeable you could overwrite the value with you own)